# Using empty char in C

Tags: c, char, printf, ternary

I want to use the ternary operator and an empty char '' to spell correctly the word "neightbor" (with or without a "s").

I want to do the following :

```
printf("There is %d neightbor%c\n", nbNeighbors,  (nbNeighbors>1)?'s':'');
```

obviously, I get an arror `error: empty character constant`

How can I menage to use this trick to get the right spelling in one `printf` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as empty character in C, but you can use an empty string instead.

Comment: You have an extra `"` in your format string by the way. Please always try to create a [mre] and then copy-paste it into the question. Every extra problem in shown code that aren't related to your question will only add distraction.

Comment: As for your case, you can either use strings instead, as shown by [Ted's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74854289/440558). Or if you don't mind a trailing space, use `' '` instead.

Comment: The correct spelling is neighbours. :)

Comment: @Neil I should add a `locale` check to the answer :-) `us_english ? "" : "u"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* use a non-printable character but they may end up looking like something else.

You'd be better off using strings:

```c
printf("There %s %d neighbor%s\n",
 nbNeighbors != 1 ? "are" : "is",
 nbNeighbors,
 nbNeighbors != 1 ? "s" : ""
);
```

Answer (score 0):

OP: "I want to use the ternary operator..."
Unless the exercise is to practice the ternary operator, committing to a particular technique blinds one to possibilites.

The example below uses 'branchless' code to deliver a grammatically correct result (ignoring the American spelling of "neighbour".)

```
printf( "There %s %d neighbor%s\n",
    "are\0is" + (nbNeighbors == 1)*4,
    nbNeighbors,
    "s" + (nbNeighbors == 1) );
```

I'd never recommend *manipulating the truth*, but *manipulating a truth value* can come in handy sometimes.

**EDIT**
The above may be difficult for some to read/understand.

Below is the same thing expressed slightly differently:

```
printf( "There %s %d neighbor%s\n",
    !(nbNeighbors-1)*4 + "are\0is",
    nbNeighbors,
    !(nbNeighbors-1) + "s" );
```

Tested, functional and branchless.

Comment: Yeah, but the goal was to do it inline, instead of doing it in multiple line like `if (nbNeighbors == 1) {...} else {...}`.Thank you anyway

Comment: This is _inline_. This solution corresponds, line for line, to the one given by @TedLyngmo, but circumvents the sometimes costly expense of "cache clearing" when pipeline prediction makes the wrong choice. You might consider that the ternary operation always uses (costly) branching...

Comment: @Fe2O3 gcc compiles my version and both your versions into equivalent assembly. My version wastes a byte because gcc doesn't make use of the fact that it could use  `"s"` for both `"s"` and `""`. https://godbolt.org/z/oTMqMj47o

Comment: @TedLyngmo All the world is not gcc... My (admittedly **old**) compiler isn't quite up to the optimisations available this century. It's assembler output does the 'classic' bifurcated jumping one of my age has come to expect. The branchless code above obviates the problem of whether or not the compiler is up-to-date. Thank you for giving it a try! It's not often I venture down into the catacombs like this `:-)`

Comment: I don't even think the compilers I used in the 80's would do jumps when it comes to selecting one of two pointers like in this case. :-) What ancient compiler _is_ that?

Comment: @TedLyngmo *blush* DevStudio '97, Visual C++ 5.0... I don't worry about turning on maximal optimisation, or such, as my interest is primarily algorithms and/or data representations (rather than speed or size.) Case in point: familiarity with 'branchless' paradigms isn't a bad thing... is it? `:-)`

Comment: _"Visual C++ 5.0"_ - Jeez, I have _Beginning Visual C++ 5_ by Ivor Horton on my shelf but I never really "got it" and went with Borland C++ Builder 4 instead :-) No, familiarity with 'branchless' paradigms sounds like a good thing :)